# how to add a number of days to a Date taken from user in oracle ADF

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

I want to iterate the one month in each row.
This my code, and when run this it doesn't iterate the months.

```
/** function receive date and integer then add the integer to the date then return the result date.
      (e.g. if you send 2013/07/13 and 5 to this function the function will return 2013/07/18 */

  public static Date addDayToOracleDate(oracle.jbo.domain.Date date, int days)
  {
    if (date != null)
    {
      Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
      c1.setTime(date.getValue());
      c1.add(Calendar.DATE, days);
      java.util.Date javaUtilDate = c1.getTime();
      long javaMilliseconds = javaUtilDate.getTime();
      java.sql.Date javaSqlDate = new java.sql.Date(javaMilliseconds);
      return new oracle.jbo.domain.Date(javaSqlDate);
    }
    return null;
  }
public void genrateActionLSNR(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

   BindingContainer bc = BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
   DCIteratorBinding CEmpLoans1Iterator = (DCIteratorBinding)bc.get("CEmpLoans1Iterator");
    DCIteratorBinding CEmpLoans1DIterator = (DCIteratorBinding)bc.get("CEmpLoansD2Iterator");


   Number loanValue = (Number)CEmpLoans1Iterator.getCurrentRow().getAttribute("LoanValue");
   Number noOfMonths = (Number)CEmpLoans1Iterator.getCurrentRow().getAttribute("NoOfMonths");
   Date firstInstallmentDate = (Date)CEmpLoans1Iterator.getCurrentRow().getAttribute("FirstInstallmentDate");

   Number result = (Number)loanValue.div(noOfMonths);
    Date hh = firstInstallmentDate;
   for(int i=0; i<noOfMonths.getValue();i++){
       addDayToOracleDate(hh, 30);
       bc.getOperationBinding("CreateInsert1").execute();

           CEmpLoans1DIterator.getCurrentRow().setAttribute("InstallmentVal", result);
       CEmpLoans1DIterator.getCurrentRow().setAttribute("LoansMonths", hh);
       System.out.println(hh);

       //bc.getOperationBinding("Commit").execute();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that each month is 30 days long, which is obviously wrong. If you want to add one month to the date, try `c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);`

Comment: While undoubtedly a correct observation, would making this change solve the OP's problem?

Comment: @APC I see your point, but if the date is 12.01 and you add 30 days, you arrive at 12.31 which is the same month

Answer (score 0):

What about creating new method at Application Module
and execute something like the following SQL statement using `PreparedStatement`

```
SELECT SYSDATE +:NO_OF_DAYS FROM DUAL;
```

replace sysdate and dual with your column and table